# Outlook Mailitem attachments count return different in Reply and Forward

Tags: vba, outlook, attachment

Windows 10 Pro 1703, Outlook 2016 64-bit

I want to count the number of attachments, images, shapes in my reply/forward message.

I found the number of items return is different in Reply and Forward message.

```
Function AttachmentImageShapeCount()
    Dim myItem As Outlook.MailItem
    Dim doc As Document

    Select Case TypeName(Application.ActiveWindow)
        Case "Explorer"
            Set myItem = ActiveExplorer.ActiveInlineResponse
        Case "Inspector"
            Set myItem = Application.ActiveInspector.CurrentItem
    End Select

    If Not myItem Is Nothing Then
        Set doc = myItem.GetInspector.WordEditor
        AttachmentImageShapeCount = myItem.Attachments.Count + doc.InlineShapes.Count + doc.Shapes.Count
        Debug.Print "Attachment: " & myItem.Attachments.Count
        Debug.Print "Image: " & doc.InlineShapes.Count
        Debug.Print "Shapes: " & doc.Shapes.Count

    End If

    Set myItem = Nothing
End Function

Sub PrintNonTextItem()
    Debug.Print "Total: " & AttachmentImageShapeCount()
End Sub
```

Add the `PrintNonTextItem` macro in ribbon or quick access toolbar.

IF the message has images or shapes, the number of attachments return differently in Reply and Forward message.

Very strange, or my code has bug?

Comment: How is this different than expected, where attachments are dropped in a Reply?

Comment: When reply a message, inline images will not count as attachment. When forward the same message, inline images will count as attachment. Weird or bug